# Coding to organize data

Tags: optimization, google-apps-script, google-sheets

So I have about 2000 entries in a spreadsheet with data about some companies. The data is organized as it follows:

> Company name: ...
> Email: .......
> Phone no: .....
> Web: ....
> address: ....
> Company name: ...
> Email: ...
> Phone no: ... 
> etc

What I want is to write a function that organizez this in another spreadsheet under the columns

> Company name      Email      Phone number      Web 
>  ......... 
>  .........

I wrote the intro to the function

```
function OrganizeData()
{var sheetFrom = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Orginial");
 var sheetTo = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Organized");
```

but then I'm not sure how to write a code that copies text after a certain keyword (email) from one row of a spreadsheet to another column from spreadsheet 2.

Comment: You will need to Split by `:` and use regex and transpose.In its present state,Your question is Too Broad and unlikely to receive answers.And the format of the data you've given is too vague to give any kind of solution.Provide your data with a screenshot & a dummy sheet with exact position of `:`,`,`, spaces between characters,number of words, Whether position of all data is in the same cell (A column) or spread across different columns, Whether there's a end of a string, Do all data contain phone numbers? Will there always be a empty row between address and the next company name? and so on..

Comment: Could you give us a representative sample of the data in the original sheet so we have something to test with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is somewhat of a guess but converts vertically positioned data into columns.

```
function testGetData()
{
  getData('SpreadSheetID','Sheet1','Sheet2'); 
}

function getData(spreadsheetId,inputSheetName,outputSheetName)
{
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId);
  var inpsh=ss.getSheetByName(inputSheetName);
  var outsh=ss.getSheetByName(outputSheetName);
  var inrg=inpsh.getDataRange();
  var invA=inrg.getValues();
  var outA=[];
  var n=0;
  outA.push(['Name','Email','Phone','Web','Address','Error']);
  var row=[];
  for(var i=0;i<invA.length;i++)
  {
    var vA=[];
    vA=String(invA[i][0]).split(':');//assuming data is in one string
    if(vA.length<2)//assuming data is split into first two columns with no : in the string
    {
      vA.push(invA[i][1]);
    }
    switch(vA[0])
    {
      case 'Company name':
        row['Name']=String(vA[1]).trim();//trim off whitespace both ends
        break;
      case 'Email':
        row['Email']=String(vA[1]).trim();
        break
      case 'Phone no':
        row['Phone']=String(vA[1]).trim();
        break;
      case 'Web':
        row['Web']=String(vA[1]).trim();
        break;
      case 'address':
        row['Address']=String(vA[1]).trim();
        outA.push([(typeof(row.Name)!='undefined')?row.Name:'',(typeof(row.Email)!='undefined')?row.Email:'',(typeof(row.Phone)!='undefined')?row.Phone:'',(typeof(row.Web)!='undefined')?row.Web:'',(typeof(row.Address)!='undefined')?row.Address:'',(typeof(row.Error)!='undefined')?row.Error:'']);
        break;
      default:
        row['Error']=Utilities.formatString('Row Error: Index: %s vA[0]= %s vA[1]= %s',i,(typeof(vA[0])!='undefined')?vA[0]:'Not Defined',(typeof(vA[1])!='undefined')?vA[1]:'Not Defined');
        break;
    }
  }
  var otrg=outsh.getRange(1,1,outA.length,outA[0].length);//determine size of output array Its good to have headers for this
  otrg.setValues(outA);
}
```

My Testing Data Sheet:

[image]

Output Sheet:

[image]

Errors: Indicate Problems with prior rows of data.

Made some changes to make it a little bit less likely to have problems.

```
function getData(spreadsheetId,inputSheetName,outputSheetName)
{
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetId);
  var inpsh=ss.getSheetByName(inputSheetName);
  var outsh=ss.getSheetByName(outputSheetName);
  var inrg=inpsh.getDataRange();
  var invA=inrg.getValues();
  var outA=[];
  var n=0;
  outA.push(['Name','Email','Phone','Web','Address','Error']);
  var row=[];
  for(var i=0;i<invA.length;i++)
  {
    var vA=[];
    vA=String(invA[i][0]).split(':');//assuming data is in one string
    if(vA.length<2)//assuming data is split into first two columns with no : in the string
    {
      vA.push(invA[i][1]);
    }
    switch(vA[0])
    {
      case 'Company name':
        row['Name']=String(vA[1]).trim();//trim off whitespace both ends
        break;
      case 'Email':
        row['Email']=String(vA[1]).trim();
        break
      case 'Phone no':
        row['Phone']=String(vA[1]).trim();
        break;
      case 'Web':
        row['Web']=String(vA[1]).trim();
        break;
      case 'address':
        row['Address']=String(vA[1]).trim();
        outA.push([(typeof(row.Name)!='undefined')?row.Name:'',(typeof(row.Email)!='undefined')?row.Email:'',(typeof(row.Phone)!='undefined')?row.Phone:'',(typeof(row.Web)!='undefined')?row.Web:'',(typeof(row.Address)!='undefined')?row.Address:'',(typeof(row.Error)!='undefined')?row.Error:'']);
        row['Name']='';//cleared out the row array
        row['Email']='';
        row['Phone']='';
        row['Address']='';
        row['Error']='';
        break;
      default:
        row['Error']=Utilities.formatString('Row Error: Index: %s vA[0]= %s vA[1]= %s',i,(typeof(vA[0])!='undefined')?vA[0]:'Not Defined',(typeof(vA[1])!='undefined')?vA[1]:'Not Defined');
        outA.push(['','','','','',row.Error]);//output errors on separate lines
        row['Error']='';//cleared errors
        break;
    }
  }
  var otrg=outsh.getRange(1,1,outA.length,outA[0].length);//determine size of output array Its good to have headers for this
  otrg.setValues(outA);
}
```

Modified Data to have some differences:

[image]

And here's the new output

[image]